# Theming views-exposed-form search block same like normal Drupal search block

Tags: search, theming

On [this page](http://www.bo-medical.com/benl/test-page), top-right you see a custom `views-exposed-form` search block. How do i theme this, so it has the same classes and HTML structure as the one below (default Drupal search block)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [block attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_attributes)

You can edit class or ID. More readable and easy to maintain.

Comment: no i think this is not working because, for example i have to get the Submit button outside a `<div>` and place it in another `<div>`. Also i have to add `<i>` in `<button>` to get the icon etc.

Comment: If you are good at CSS, you can control them. All your search form are under #block-views-exp-search-page-page and your bottom one is #block-views-events-block-1. Example if you can to change search form button. #block-views-events-block-1 input{width: 200px}

Comment: #block attributes can change those complicated ID to a simple one. Example:  #block-views-events-block-1 change to #bottom_block

Comment: i can control it with css and its classes, but how do i theme it and how do i change it's HTML structure?

Comment: @MeesFrenkelFrank, any example?